# Python read a file in zip archives from api call

Tags: python-2.7, rest, api, zip, httpwebresponse

I have a restful endpoint which my rest api could make a get request to it and the file is a zip file. In this zip file, there're 2 files. I only want to read the content in 1 file from this zip archives. I was able to do a test and it likes my code stuck on line file=zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response_object.content)).

class ZipFileResponseHandler:

```
def __init__(self,**args):
    self.csv_file_to_index = args['csv_file_to_index']

def __call__(self, response_object, raw_response_output, response_type, req_args, endpoint):
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response_object.content))
    for name in file.namelist():
        if re.match(name, self.csv_file_to_index):
            data =file.read(name)
            print_xml_stream(repr(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution to my own answer. Because I use python 2.7 the corresponding method that use to handle the response_object is StringIO not BytesIO. So the line:

file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response_object.content))

should be

file = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(response_object.content))